# If matrix $M$ represents rotation around the origin, how to represent rotation about another point in terms of $M$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

For homework from school I have to made some tasks. There are no lessons because it is a second change.

my question is: Multiplication by matrix $M$ represents rotation around the origin. If we do not want to rotate, to the origin, but to a point $p$ which is obtained by translation of the origin of vector $t$ and use is made of column vectors, which of the four products below shows the matrix of the required rotation around $p$ (circle the correct answer).

- $T ^ {-1} M T$
- $T M T ^ {-1}$
- $M ^ {-1} T M$
- $M T M ^ {-1}$
- None of the above product matrices

I really don't have an idea how to do this question. Can someone help me with this question.

Comment: What happens to the universe, if you first translate point $p$ to the origin, then rotate it about origin, and then translate origin back to $p$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen the universe is in the same position ?

Comment: You only cancelled the translation - you didn't cancel the rotation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So it is only rotated about the origin ?

Comment: No. It was rotated about the point that happened to reside in the origin at the time of the rotation.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen okay, but can you tell me what the answer of my question is ?

Comment: I think I already did! Do you know how the composition of affine transformations is done using the matrices?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry, but i dont get it. i dont know how the composition of affine transformations is done.

Comment: See my question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093314/rotation-matrix-and-of-rotation-around-a-point